# Transforming text with neural network

Tags: neural-network

I previously worked with neural networks, but just for fun mainly using them with normalized Categorical(enum),Numeric and Bit(bool) values. I know NNs have trouble understanding characters, but I was wondering if they could understand how to transform text.

So is it possible for example to train NN to do following:

- 13/20 = 20
- aa/bb = bb
- 20/10 = 10

Or (replaced d with f)

- abcde = abcfe
- tdfg = tffg
- ddhj = ffhj

If yes, how reliably? Or maybe there is something better suited for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question wasn't related to implementation but since I have just finished a lab on a similar topic, here are some practical tips:

It would be quite possible and easy to use a RNN network to transform the text in that way. Clone this (https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn) repository and train it with a file placed in data/folder/input.txt with enough size in the same format you want the output:

```
abcde = abcfe
tdfg = tffg
ddhj = ffhj
```

use this command to train:

```
th train.lua -data_dir data/folder
```

When testing the network it should be able to produce a correct output based on the seed text you provide:

```
th sample.lua cv/[latest_sample] -primetext "abcd" -length 7
```

should be able to produce the output:

```
abcd = abcf
```

Comment: Very nice proof of concept, Ill accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on complexity of the transformation. If you are interested in these examples, then, certanly yes, this is doable and reliable. Second example is trivial, you just present NN one character at the time, encode input and output as one-hot vector (one neuron per character) and it will do the job. First example can be solved by converting left and right part to one-hot input vector representing one of all possible combinations of two symbols and having two outputs, asking NN to select if first part or second part should be selected (better ways to encode input exists, especially for long strings). Provided you have enough training examples, everything should work fine.

Generally, days when it was prohibitively difficut for NNs to deal with texts are long gone. Now NNs can be trained to do machine translation (better then any other method) and even, to some extent, trained to predict  output of simple computer programs based on program character string (but this is still difficult task for NNs).

Comment: Thank you, it's been a while since I worked with NNs. I guess I will have to run some tests to see what the limits are, but just the confirmation that NN could handle it, is a lot. I understand part of your answer about first example, but the thing is I don't know how string was changed, I just have source and result, and I would have to train it so it produce same result from my input. So I will have 36 inputs 1/0 for each char, thats how I imagened it being done.

Comment: Note, that if your transformation depends also on past history, not only current character, you should use recurrent neural networks and arbitrary long-time dependencies can be difficult to deal with. If you data source is complex, you might want to generate some synthetic data with known transform and first expirement with that to get some confidence.